# How to connect gazebo turtlebot and running in RViz?

Tags: gazebo, rviz, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a plan to start working on gazebo for simulation turtlebot first and then use the turtlebot simulator in RViz.

How to connect it?

I appreciate any help and pointers in any direction.

Thanks. :

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246745/how-to-connect-gazebo-turtlebot-and-running-in-rviz?/) by [Chucolate](https://answers.ros.org/users/28340/chucolate/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-10-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JoshMarino](https://answers.ros.org/users/27952/joshmarino/) on 2016-10-29**:
Need robot state publisher and joint state publisher. Don't have example code on this computer to share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recommend looking going through the simulation track of http://learn.turtlebot.com/

There are also simulation tutorials here: http://wiki.ros.org/action/show/Robots/TurtleBot

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0